# How can I configure /etc/hosts file to point to apache web server?

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, hosts

I have installed apache web server and I need to point 127.1.1.1 with alias (www.someaddress.lan) to local apache. What is the proper way to do it? How to point someaddress.lan to default apache page and www.someaddress.lan to /var/www/wordpress/?

Answer (score 12):

For your hosts file:

```
127.1.1.1     someaddress.lan www.someaddress.lan
```

By the way, don't you mean 127.0.0.1?  That is the loopback ip address for localhost. If so, use the following:

```
127.0.0.1     someaddress.lan www.someaddress.lan localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Then you need to edit your apache server config file.  Usually /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
That is where you associate sub domains (Virtual Hosts) with directories containing the content the apache server serves.

[Apache Name Based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.someaddress.lan
ServerAlias www.someaddress.lan
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName someaddress.lan
ServerAlias someaddress.lan
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do without installing any kind of DNS server in your machine, then you can put an entry into `/etc/hosts` file.

```
 127.1.1.1    www.someaddress.lan    someaddress.lan
```

Actually ever host before resolving the domain name by contacting its DNS server, first checks its own `/etc/hosts` file. If it founds that domain entry in that file, it doesn't contact its DNS server.

**EDIT:** You have to add entries for each in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName    someaddress.lan
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName    www.someaddress.lan
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/wordpress
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to restart the `apache2` server after changing the above configuration file by the following command:

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks! How to point *someaddress.lan* to default apache page and *www.someaddress.lan* to */var/www/wordpress/*?

Comment: Did you mean to enter the `VirtualHost *` as `VirtualHost *:80` instead? I am having issues being able to access my apache2 server from the internet